# Go to app page in Flutter push notification

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, push

I have a problem with Notification on Flutter app. I would like to redirect the user from a notification to a specific page. I have right now something like this:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
         _goToMessage(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
         _goToMessage(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
         _goToMessage(message);
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      print("Push Messaging token: $token");
    });
  }

  void _goToMessage(message) {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, DidacticList.routeName);
  }
```

This code gives me an error:
`Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator`.

After receiving a push notification code from `onLaunch()` or `onResume()` executing.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass context from main.dart like following, while initializing Push Notification.

put this in your build method of the MaterialApp Widget.

```
  //  init Firebase Push Notification Service...
  PushNotificationsManager(context).init();
```

After BuildContext initialized you can use it as per your choice.

Here's the PushNotificationsManager Class for your reference.

```
class PushNotificationsManager {
  bool _initialized = false;
  static BuildContext _context;
  Stream<RemoteMessage> _receivedMessages;
  PushNotificationsManager._(_context);

  factory PushNotificationsManager(BuildContext context) {
    _context = context;
    return _instance;
  }

  static final PushNotificationsManager _instance =
      PushNotificationsManager._(_context);

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future<void> init() async {
    if (!_initialized) {
      await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
      _receivedMessages = FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp;
      //  * Implement on Background Message like follwing...
      // FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((message) => );
      //  TODO : Implement on message received...
      _receivedMessages.listen((message) {});
      _initialized = true;
    }
  }
}
```

You can use listen or onBackgroundMessage method to navigate to any page on navigation click.

Comment: The description for `onBackgroundMessage` states "This provided handler must be a top-level function and cannot be anonymous otherwise an [ArgumentError] will be thrown." unfortunately the ((message) =>) is not a top-level funtion